# Swift equivalent of arrayWIthObjects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsarray

This is in Obj C:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kLMEnglish,nil];
```

Can someone tell me the swift equivalent for this line of code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code :

```
var myVar1: Int = 50
var myVar2: Int = 50

var array: NSArray? = NSArray(objects: myVar1,myVar2)
```

Answer (score 12):

What about this?

```
let arr = [kLMEnglish]
```

In ObjC you could also write:

```
NSArray *arr = @[kLMEnglish];
```

Comment: No it is not this, i found the solution by my self, its like this:
var array: NSArray? = NSArray(object: kLMEnglish)
Thank you.

Comment: why wasn't my suggestion working? Did you try: `var arr = [kLMEnglish]`?

Comment: I didn't try your suggestion, coz i founded the solution, so thank you for your work. :)

Comment: The point is, @sergio’s version is the idiomatic way to do it.  While the accepted answer compiles, you shouldn’t use it (stylistically subjectively speaking that is – but there’s a reason it’s been heavily upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

In swift you can use array blow like that

```
let array: NSArray = [kLMEnglish]     

var array:NSArray! = [kLMEnglish]

var arrayMutable = [kLMEnglish] as NSArray
let arrayImmutable = [kLMEnglish] as NSArray


var array = [kLMEnglish]

// if it is String
var array: [String] = [kLMEnglish]

// if it is Integer
var array:[Int] = [kLMEnglish]
```

If beginning of the line begins with **var**, which means variable and allows the **contents of the array to be changed** in the future.

If beginning of the line begins with **let**, which means constant and means the **contents can not be changed** in the future.